# Not able to override airflow.cfg variables from values.yaml

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

```
airflow:
  extraEnvVars:
    - name: "AIRFLOW__API__ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL_API"
      value: "True"
    - name: "AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND"
      value: "airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth"
```

i am using this in the values.yaml, but still the values is not reflecting in the /opt/bitnami/airflow/airflow.cfg

```
/opt/bitnami/airflow$ grep -ri auth_back airflow.cfg
auth_backend=airflow.api.auth.backend.deny_all
```

Answer (score 0):

i was upgrading to airflow 2.2.4. in that version they didn't had this extraEnvVars section under airflow, so i have include all my variables under airflow.web.extraEnvVars and it worked as before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using in version `2.7.1`

```
        extraEnv: |
          - name: AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__DAG_DIR_LIST_INTERVAL
            value: "30"
          - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES
            value: "False"
...
```

I downloaded helm (we are running via argo) and saved all values - it shows which syntax is working for our version.